# Save the output to a c program Variable

Tags: c, shell

I have a shell script program which gives some output.  I need the output from the script and store in the c program.

Comment: How do you intend to "store a value in a program"?

Comment: I want to get some strings from some text files with awk.And,store the strings in virables of C program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres two ways you can do this:

1. Run the program from within the C program, using something like this: [How to execute a command and get output of command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c) The answer is written for C++ but it's all the same calls as in C.
2. Pipe the output of the other program into your C program. This means your C program won't be executed before the other program though. For example, the command:

   ls | myprog

will take the output of "ls" and feed it into myprog, which can read it via scanf or fgets, for example.

Comment: Good!! : @OP below I implementation of 2 option